# How to solve vanished wordpress designed pages

Tags: wordpress

I made 6 pages out of which 3 pages were not there it vanished, tried to look at the trash box but it was not there.

checked all plugins, themes & settings but didn't find any problems. After contacting my hosting customer service they also don't know why this is happening, I have had to take backup more than 3 times in the last month.

Comment: I would check the backup. The pages should be there. Are they still in the current database? Or did they disappear there too?